# Conditional Expectation

Tags: probability-theory

I am learning conditional expectation for fun. I cannot solve the following problem, I think it is just my vocabulary is limited. This problem came from a book on Stochastic Processes:

Let $\Omega = [0,1]\times [0,1]$ with the usual Lebesgue measure and $\sigma$-algebra of Borel sets. Let $X$ and $Y$ be random variables on $\Omega$ with joint density
$$ f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ccc} x+y & \text{ if }& x,y\in [0,1] \\ 0 & \text{ if }& \text{ otherwise} \end{array} \right. $$
Show that $\displaystyle E(X|Y) = \frac{2 + 3Y}{3 + 6Y}$.

The part that I do not understand is in the solutions, the author begins by writing, 
$$ Y^{-1} (B) = [0,1] \times B $$
where $B$ is a Borel set in $[0,1]$.

How can be possibly say that? There is no reason at all why $X$ and $Y$ are defined by different coordinates. Unless I completely misunderstand what it means to be of "joint density".

Comment: As explained below, this assumes implicitely that $(X,Y):(x,y)\mapsto(x,y)$ on $\Omega=[0,1]^2$. What is your source?

Comment: @Did "Basic Stochastic Processes" by Brezniak. How do you know that this is what it implicitly assumes?

Comment: 'Cause this is by far the simplest way to define $(X,Y)$ on $\Omega=[0,1]^2$ with the desired joint distribution.

Comment: Note however that the identity of the probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal F,P)$ and of the random variables $(X,Y)$ is irrelevant to solve the exercise; all that is needed is the joint distribution of $(X,Y)$, characterized by the PDF $f_{X,Y}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is to establish the following for Borel set $B\subseteq [0,1]$,
$$\begin{align}
\mathsf P(Y\in B)
 & = \iint_{Y^{-1}(B)} f_{X,Y}(x,y) \mathrm dx\mathrm dy
\\
 & = \iint_{[0;1]\times B} f_{X,Y}(x,y) \mathrm dx\mathrm dy
\\
& = \int_B \int_0^1 (x+y) \mathrm dx\mathrm dy
\\
&  =\int_B (y + \frac 1 2 ) \mathrm dy.
\end{align}$$

Thus, the marginal PDF $f_Y(y)$ is $y+\frac 1 2$ for $y\in [0;1]$, and $0$ otherwise.

In fact, the joint density of $X$ and $Y$ tells us how $X: \Omega\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $Y:\Omega\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are distributed with $X(x,y)=x$ and $Y(x,y)=y$. We have for any Borel set $A\subseteq [0,1]\times [0,1]$,

$$P((X,Y)\in A) = \iint_A f_{X,Y}(x,y)  \mathrm dx\mathrm dy.$$
Thus, 
$$\begin{align}
(x,y)\in Y^{-1}(B) 
& \iff Y(x,y) \in B
\\ & \iff x\in [0,1] \wedge y\in B
\\ & \iff (x,y)\in [0;1]\times B
\end{align}$$

Comment: I am sorry, this does not answer my question. I can do the computations, I do not understand why $Y^{-1}(B) = [0,1]\times B$?

Comment: I have explained it at the end.

Comment: Define $f:[0,1]^2\to \mathbb{R}$ as $f(x,y) = 0$. Let $B = \{0\}$. Then $f^{-1}(B) = [0,1]^2$, it is not equal to $[0,1]\times B$.

Comment: The random variable $Y$ takes $(x,y)$ to $y$.

Comment: Can you please explain why? (I think my vocabulary is limited.) I thought a random variable is any measurable function from $\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: That has to be from the joint density.

Comment: Is it possible for you to write up a quick explanation of how it follows from definition of joint density, in your original post? So that I can upvote and mark it as answered.

Comment: It is edited now.

Answer (score 0):

we can write 
$ E(X|Y)=\int_X xf(x|y)dx$

but $f(x|y)=\frac{f(x,y)}{f(y)}$

and
$ f(y)=\int_X f(x,y)dx=\int_{0}^{1} (x+y)dx=(x^2/2+xy |_0^1)=1/2+y$

Also

$$ E(X|Y)=\int_X xf(x|y)dx=\int_{0}^{1}x \frac{x+y}{1/2+y} dx$$

$$ =\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^2+xy}{1/2+y} dx=\frac{1}{1/2+y} (x^3/3+x^2y/2|_0^1)$$
$$ = \frac{(1/3-y/2)}{(1/2+y)}=\frac{2+3y}{3+6y}$$